# Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file - Chelsa climate tif file

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, r-raster, geotiff

I downloaded Chelsa bio files on my local directory.
And when I tried to create raster for my R project, I keep getting error with following message.

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

My code was simple and I was able to create worldclim climate raster file with the same code.
and, cannot figure out the difference.

```
download.file(url = "https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/climatologies/1981-2010/bio/CHELSA_bio1_1981-2010_V.2.1.tif", 
              destfile = "Chelsa/bio1.tif")
bio1 <- raster("Chelsa/bio1.tif")
```

Could anyone advice on this?

I also tried

bio1 <- stack("Chelsa/bio1.tif")

But, similar error message popped out.

I also changed my directory - instead of putting it under subdirectory (named Chelsa), I directly put the file into my home directory. But, all didn't work.